# Bean Validation - JSR-303 DuplicateItemCheck for a list in java

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

Is there any standard bean validation annotation to check duplicate item in a collection in java.
or Anyone implemented custom validation to check duplicate in a list using bean validation.

for example

```
    public class MySecurityRequest{
        private Date dob;

        @DuplicateNotAllowed
        private List securityQuestions;
    }

    public class SecurityQuestion{
      private String question;
      private String answer;
    }
```

Here i need to make sure that, questions are not repeated in the list.
Are one faced this similar issue?

Comment: Why not use a `Set`? You could even use a sorted set if you need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah ah funny you ask. We just added the @UniqueElements annotation to Hibernate Validator (the PR was merged today - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/879).

It will be part of 6.0.5.Final that we plan to release tomorrow.

Note that it is not a standard constraint (i.e. it's not in Bean Validation) but it will be supported by HV out of the box.

You should be able to use HV 6 with Spring: it should be compatible. Just be careful about your dependencies (you can't have both versions in your dependencies - the group ids of HV 5 and 6 are different - and also be careful about the javax.el dependency - see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator#using-hibernate-validator for the details).

Comment: I just took a look of this Pul request. it's really awesome. i just did overlook of it. saw tests for only simple type collections. will it work for custom classes and multiple properties inside?

Comment: one more think i have to use latest hibernate-validator :(.

Comment: You need to implement your equals() and hashCode() methods and it will work with any object types. And yes, you will need to use the latest version. But it's compatible. And faster.

Comment: Since we are using natural order. we might get into a problem of "if i want to use one field to determine duplicate and different fields as identify unique object" Was there any suggestion/consideration for this kind of situation?

Comment: You would need a specific class level constraint for that.

Comment: @Gullaume I am trying to write a similar constraint to check duplicates(by either of a property out of two in an object). Can't use UniqueElement since need to override equals for either of a property in an object. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet this seems impossible, By any chance this can be used/written a new validator to check validator. Where duplicate is checked for either of a property in multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set. And override and implement hashcode() and equals() methods on your SecurityQuestion class to help the Set identify duplicates.

Comment: Set removes the duplicate i agree. but i want do to validation of request object. i don't want to remove/ignore one item in the collection.

Comment: Then override the hashcode and equals as said. Then create a set from the list. Like new HashSet(securityQuestions) and compare the size of the list and set to assert if there are any duplicates.